# Como fazer um Reset em um GridView c# .aspnet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho duas tabelas(***DataTable***) diferentes e preciso utilizá-las em um mesmo `Gridview`. Porém quando chamo o `Gridview` na tela ele sempre assume o valor da primeira tabela.

Alguém sabe como fazer um `Gridview` que se adapte a qualquer consulta?

```
dt = info.RetornaInfo(x,y);
GdvInfo.DataSource = dt;
GdvInfo.DataBind();
```

Comment: Esses `DataTable` tem a mesma número de colunas e são respectivas e valores e tipos!

Comment: Poste também o exemplo de dois `DataTable` que são diferentes para que as respostas sejam elaboradas de acordo com eles.

Answer (score 2):

Você vai precisar setar o `DataSource` como `null` e depois limpar as linhas do `DataGridView`.

```
GdvInfo.DataSource = null;
GdvInfo.Rows.Clear(); 

dt = info.RetornaInfo(x,y);
GdvInfo.DataSource = dt;
GdvInfo.DataBind();
```

---

<sub>Resposta anterior removida.</sub>

Comment: Desta forma ?         public void CarregaGrid()
        {
GdvInfo.DataSource = null;
GdvInfo.Rows.Clear(); 
           
            dt = info.RetornaInfo(x, y);
            GdvInfo.DataSource = dt;
            GdvInfo.DataBind();

        }

Comment: Não. Da forma que tá na resposta.

Comment: Quando tento colocar o GdvInfo.Row.Clear() ele retorna o seguinte erro:System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for
'Clear' and no extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' could be found (are you missing
a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Tira essa linha aí, eu devo ter confundido com Windows Forms.

Comment: Não deu erro de código ,mais, o grid utiliza as informações e a estrutura da tabela anterior.